# Calculus: Finding an unknown coefficient in continuous equations

Tags: calculus

I am watching a video trying to understand continuity in calculus. The author first starts with the $ax - 4, x < 1$, and we are trying to find the value of "a".

The author subsequently derives $ax - 4$ as $7x - 4$, where $a = 7$.

Why did he come to a conclusion where $a$ is $7$, where $x < 1$?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is right, since $$\lim_{x\to 1^-}ax-4=a-4$$ and $$f(1)=1$$ so we get
$$a-4=3$$ as you stated.

Answer (score 1):

A function is continuous in $x=c$ if its left- and right-hand limits in $c$ are equal.

In the case of $c=1$, this comes down to:
$$\lim_{x \to 1^+}\color{blue}{f(x)} = \lim_{x \to 1^-}\color{red}{f(x)} \tag{$*$}$$
Now for the right-hand limit you have $x > 1$ and you need the blue part while for the left-hand limit you have $x < 1$ and you need the red part of the function:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\color{blue}{3x^2} & x \ge 1\\
\color{red}{ax-4} & x<1\end{cases}$$
That turns $(*)$ into:
$$\lim_{x \to 1^+}\left(\color{blue}{3x^2}\right)= \lim_{x \to 1^-}\left(\color{red}{ax-4}\right)$$
And then you get:
$$3\cdot 1^2 = a \cdot 1 -4 \iff 3=a-4 \iff a = 7$$